# Spacing between citations within a bracket

Tags: spacing, citing

I am currently using citations in the format `[1,2,3,4]`. However, I need spacing between the numbers i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you use a citation management package (`cite`?, `natbib`?). Please also tell us which bibliography style you use.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use numeric-style citation call-outs, with citation numbers encased in square brackets. You may achieve your formatting objective by loading the `natbib` citation management package with the options `numbers` and `square`:

```
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
```